# Dragging an item from a QTableView/QSqlTableModel

Tags: drag-and-drop, qt4

I want to be able to drag an item (actually a whole row) from a QTableView that has a QSqlTableModel as it's model.

`QSqlTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index)` doesn't return `Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled.` Does that mean the only way I can get this to work is if I subclass QSqlTableModel and reimplement the `flags()` method?

Thats seems like overkill just to drag the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is the only way to get it to work.